# jquery set css on trigger click

Tags: jquery, function

i am trying to set css on trigger click, i have an code in which i am triggering click function on a particular li. the function is triggering on particular li properly but i need to set css with triggering on particular li , the li border should be change on triggering.

My code is :

```
$(".two-buttons > .form-preview").click(function(){             
    $('#myModal').show();   
    selectedimage = $('.form-preview').attr('name');
    $('#hide-content > div').not('.'+selectedimage).hide();
    $('.resume01 > ul > li').find('li').attr('name', selectedimage).trigger('click');
});
```

i need to set this `.css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});` on li that are clicked by function.

please suggest , how i can set css on particular li when the function is trigger on particular li.

Comment: Please add related html in your post

Comment: why didn't you try this..? `.trigger('click').css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});`

Comment: Can you please add fiddler for your code ?

Comment: i tried it but it can't set the css property.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine right after click with dot using [end](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

```
$('.resume01 > ul > li')
.find('li')
.attr('name', selectedimage)
.trigger('click')
.end()
.attr('name', selectedimage)
.css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});
```

Also, try this:

```
$.when($('.resume01 > ul > li')
    .find('li')
    .attr('name', selectedimage)
    .triggerHandler('click'))
    .done(functino(){
    $(this)
    .css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});
    });
```

Comment: I need css on particular li that are selected using this $('.resume01 > ul > li').find('li').attr('name', selectedimage).trigger('click')

Answer (score 0):

You can do two thins

1. `$('.resume01 > ul > li').find('li').attr('name', selectedimage).trigger('click').css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});`
2. Set css in  event  handler 
   `$('.resume01 > ul > li').click(function(){
   $(this).css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});
   });`

Comment: can you please post related html code, i feel there must be some thing is wrong because you are finding li in ul> li

Comment: and if there is only ul > li then i had update my code try now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define click function on your li like this:

```
$('.resume01 > ul).on("click", "li", function() {
        $(this).css({"border-color":"#4A8107","border-width":"3px","border-style":"solid"});
    });
});
```